# How to correctly display image in a <li> element?

Tags: html, css

Ok this is simple thing. I firstly created a usual "Home" Button linking to the Home Page of the website, but the word "Home" looked too obvious. Hence I tried to insert an icon in place of that word, but its not fitting properly. I have tried some things in my css but its messing up the whole  (used to create the navigation menu). The screenshot is attached. Please if someone can see whats wrong.[image]

CSS:-

```
 ul#menu
{
padding: 0px;
position: relative;
margin: 0;

}
ul#menu li
{
display: inline;
text-decoration:solid;

}
ul#menu li a 
{
color: black;
background-color: #f5b45a;
padding: 10px 20px;
text-decoration: none;
line-height: 2.8em;
/*CSS3 properties*/
border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
}
```

HTML:-

```
<ul id="menu">
    <li id="Home_Link"><a href="Home"><img src="../../Image_Data/Home_Icon.ico" id="Home_Icon"/></a></li>
    <li><a href="Men">MEN</a></li>
    <li><a href="Women">WOMEN</a></li>
    <li><a href="Kids">KIDS</a></li>
    <li><a href="Design">DESIGN!!</a></li>
```

Comment: You need to provide code samples. Do you really expect an answer from just that image?

Comment: try `align` attribute for `<img>` tag

Comment: @EL Depreciated in HTML4 and not supported in HTML5

Comment: Ok, try `vertical-align` style... UPD: it's already in 1st answer =))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your current styles you will need to play around with the vertical-alignment and margins for the image, something like:

```
ul#menu li#Home_Link a img {
  vertical-align: text-bottom;
  margin-bottom: -5px;
}
```

As a side note, your use of ID's for elements is not recommended - use classes if needed. And reduce the specificity of your style declarations, e.g. .home-link img

Comment: Thanx but I was designing the header of the website, which is common to all pages. So i thought it was a good idea to create multiple IDs and classes in this part, so that styling can be controlled more effectively with CSS changes only when needed. Anyways thanks for the tips. I'm very new to web designing.

Comment: No problem, happy to help. ID's can seem to be a great help when starting out, but they very quickly lead to specificity issues and having to write very complex selectors in your stylesheets. Use ID's sparingly, and replace with unique classes when you can.